# how to take the target output value of ajaxform to a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, ajaxform

I have a file uploader with an ajaxForm technic. 
How to take the output of the php file in a function instead of the **'target'** of the jqueryForm **output**, to do some stuff with JS?

e.g. i want to take the imagefile name output from the php file

```
echo 'media/'.$NewFileName.'';
```

so it will be like:

> media/IMG_4321.jpg

here is my uploader

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
        target: 'output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response     
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

 jQuery('#mediaForm').submit(function() { 
        jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options);           
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    });
```

...

and php file management

```
    echo '<p style="color:#46A81E; font-family: light;">Success! File Uploaded.</p>';
    if($File_Ext=='.jpg' || $File_Ext=='.jpg' || $File_Ext=='.png' || $File_Ext=='.gif' )
    {
        //echo "<img src='media/".$NewFileName."' id='preview' class='img-responsive'>";
        echo 'media/'.$NewFileName.'';
    }
    if($File_Ext=='.mp3' ||$File_Ext=='.mpeg' || $File_Ext=='.wav')
    {
        echo '<audio controls id="preview">
                      <source src="media/'.$NewFileName.'" type="audio/mpeg">
                      <source src="media/'.$NewFileName.'" type="audio/mp3">
                      <source src="media/'.$NewFileName.'" type="audio/x-wav">
                      <source src="media/'.$NewFileName.'" type="audio/basic">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>';
    }
```

...

Comment: not familiar with the function but I guess if you leave target emtpy ('') or if it is needed direct to hidden output and use something like `success:       afterSuccess(response)` it might work.

Comment: actually i found it! it's similar on what you are saying. In the afterSuccess function i putted my function which handles the output, i left empty the target option and all now its fine. Thank you btw.